# Addressing from a Docker container with a web application to a container with a VPN client

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wrote myself docker-compose.yml in which there are three containers:

```
version: '3'
services:

  wireguard:
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/wireguard
    container_name: wireguard
    privileged: true 
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.0.2
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/wg0.conf:/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.0.3
    restart: always

  nodejs:
    image: node:14
    privileged: true
    command: >
      bash -c "npm install && npm start"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ./proxy/env.file:/app/env.file
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - wireguard
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.0.4
    restart: always
    
networks:
  net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.0.0/24
```

The nodejs container deploys my first web application.
The nginx container sits in front of this first web application. All requests from the client come first to nginx, and it sends them to nodejs. This works well.
The wireguard container establishes a connection to another server with a other white ip. That is, the wireguard container is a wireguard client. There is also a second web application on another server, and I need to have access to it. I tried ping the ip of my second web application in a wireguard container and it works well:

```
docker-compose exec wireguard ping 192.168.20.94
PING 192.168.20.94 (192.168.20.94) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.20.94: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=116 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.20.94: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=56.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.20.94: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=57.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.20.94: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=57.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.20.94: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=57.1 ms
```

Now, I would like to send a get request from my first web application located in a nodejs container. I tried this, I got a 504 error.
I tried to ping ip inside a nodejs container and got the error:

```
docker-compose exec nodejs ping 192.168.20.94
PING 192.168.20.94 (192.168.20.94) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 192.168.20.94 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 110ms
```

How can I access the second server at 192.168.20.94 from a nodejs container?

Visual diagram:
[image]